# ESLint rule for spaces in union types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, eslint

Is there an ESLint rule for TypeScript that allows enforcing using space in the following situation?

```
// good
let a: string | number = 4;

// bad
let a: string|number = 4;
```

The only stuff that might be helpful are `type-annotation-spacing` and `space-infix-ops` rules but they do not seem to work with union types.

Answer (score 3):

Seems the rule [`@typescript-eslint/space-infix-ops`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/space-infix-ops.md) has been recently (May 2021) updated to handle this.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/51
(Not sure why the issue is still open)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you want, but won't `eslint-plugin-prettier` do this for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use prettier in this project.

Comment: I've not seen any new eslint stuff that deals with auto fixing formatting since Prettier became popular I'm afraid it is becoming the only game in town in that regard

Comment: Hmm, so maybe it is worth to check Prettier, thanks!